# how to configure cassandra to listen to jmx port on real ip address and not 0.0.0.0?

Tags: cassandra

I want to make cassandra to litsen to jmx on external ip and not 0.0.0.0 as it used in default.
I've added the flag in cassandra-env but it still starts up on the 0.0.0.0 inteface

```
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.host=172.16.40.60"
```

What else should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add this:

`JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=172.16.40.60"`

this line is from `cassandra-env.sh` in `apache/cassandra`, see here: [cassandra-env.sh#L204](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/6ab4bd7a1a357a2709d6958f6c153270c3a4f8fa/conf/cassandra-env.sh#L204)

Comment: If it matters to anyone I was able to use this in 2.0.9 so it still seems valid now

Answer (score 2):

Currently you can not configure jmx in cassandra to listen on just a single interface. This is due to it being quite hard to do in java applications in general. If you are attempting to do this for security reasons then the solution is often to block the jmx port for all interfaces except localhost and then use a tunnel to access jmx from the local node.

For the discussion on adding this feature to cassandra see:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-2967

And a potential workaround:

https://blogs.oracle.com/jmxetc/entry/jmx_connecting_through_firewalls_using

Comment: I want to do this not because the security reasons. I wanted to setup a cluster of 4 nodes on 2 PC. But in this case I can not create two nodes on the same pc with same JMX port. I can configure different jmx ports, but I'll have a problem with the ops senter, cause there is only one JMX port I can configure for a cluster, and not per instance.

Comment: The OpsCenter agents are what uses JMX. You can configure opscenter agents to use different ports if needed. See http://www.datastax.com/support-forums/topic/multiple-opscenter-agents#post-2641